# Compute value of $\pi$ up to 8 digits

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I am quite lost on how approximate the value of $\pi$ up to 8 digits with a confidence of 99% using Monte Carlo. I think this requires a large number of trials but how can I know how many trials?

I know that a 99% confidence interval is 3 standard deviations away from the mean in a normal distribution. From the central limit theorem the standard deviation of the sample mean (or standard error) is proportional to the standard deviation of the population $\sigma_{\bar X} = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$

So I have something that relates the size of the sample (i.e. number of trials) with the standard deviation, but then I don't know how to proceed from here. How does the "8 digit precision" comes into play?

**UPDATE**

Ok I think I am close to understand it. From CLT we have $\displaystyle \sigma_{M} = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$ so in this case $\sigma = \sqrt{p(1-p)}$ therfore $\displaystyle \sigma_{M} = \frac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{\sqrt{N}}$

Then from the Bernoulli distribution, $\displaystyle \mu = p = \frac{\pi}{4}$ therefore

$$\sigma_{M}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi(4-\pi)}}{\sqrt{N}}$$ but what would be the value of $\sigma_{M}$? and then I have $\pi$ in the formula but is the thing I am trying to approximate so how does this work? and still missing the role of the 8 digit precision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may completely off the mark, but I guess that *Monte Carlo* here refers to approximating some integral by a random process, and that the integral must be chosen in a way that knowing its value allows us to calculate $\pi$.

Let's guess that the integral we are interested in is
$$
\frac\pi4=\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx
$$
giving the probability that a random point in the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ (so $x$ and $y$ independent and uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$) is also in the unit disk.

Assume that we generate $N$ such points $(x,y)$ and record the number of successes (points in the unit disk) $M$. We know from crude estimates for $\pi$, say $3<\pi<4$, that the success rate $p$ of an individual point is between $3/4$ and $1$. Therefore the standard deviation of $M$ is bounded from above by
$$\sigma(M)=\sqrt{Np(1-p)}<\frac{\sqrt{3N}}4.$$

We approximate
$$
\pi\approx\frac{4M}N.
$$
This has SD $\sigma(\pi)<4\sigma(M)/N=\sqrt{3/N}$.

For 99% confidence we want $3\sigma(\pi)<10^{-8}$ or equivalently $\sqrt{N}>3\sqrt{3}\cdot 10^8$. This suggests that generating $N\approx 27\cdot10^{16}$ random points on the unit square would do the trick :-)

After this gedankenexperiment I quite appreciate Machin's formula. Even the alternating series for $\arctan 1$ beats this.

So this leaves open the possibility that something completely different was wanted?

Comment: Thanks. Indeed this is what I wanted, but there is something I didn't get. I agree that $\pi$ can be approximated by $4M/N$, i.e. number of success (points lying inside the circle) divided by the total number of points. But then how is that you are able to say that $\sigma(\pi) = \sqrt{3/N}$ ?? Is it possible to put this in such a way that I can see the use of the central limit theorem?

Comment: I was treating $M$= the number of successful outcomes as a random variable, and $N$ a fixed number (yet to be determined). So as $\pi=4M/N$ we should have $\sigma(\pi)=4\sigma(M)/N<\sqrt{3N}/N=\sqrt{3/N},$ I think. I'm a bit rusty with my probability terminology (particularly in English), so I may refer to something with a incorrect term.

Comment: Re: Central Limit Theorem. Selecting a single random point from the square is Bernoulli trial with success rate $p=\pi/4$, so its variance is given by $\sigma^2=p(1-p)$. The variance of $N$ independent Bernoulli trials is thus $\sigma(M)=Np(1-p)$.  The variable $M$ really follows a binomial distribution, but I am approximating it (here is where CLT is used) as a normally distributed random variable with expected value $N\pi/4$ and variance $\sigma(M)^2=Np(1-p)$.

Comment: Can you please see my update in the question?

Comment: Ok. In your formula $\sigma/\sqrt{N}$ the numerator $\sigma$ refers to the SD of a single Bernoulli trial. So here $\sigma=\sqrt{p(1-p)}$

Comment: Another update. I just notice that I have the value of $\pi$ in the formula of the standard error. Is this right? Still how to include the 8 digit precision?

Comment: I interpreted *8 digit precision* as meaning that the 99% confidence interval of $4M/N$ has width at most $2\cdot 10^{-8}$. I guess that means just that the error is less than $10^{-8}$ with a probability exceeding 99%. It may well be that *8-digit precision* includes the leading 3 and seven decimals. In that case you would require $3\sigma_M<0.5\cdot 10^{-7}$ instead of my more stringent requirement. I think that you can give yourself some slack here in interpreting this. Unless you have had relatively similar examples in class, in which case you should follow your teacher's interpretation.

Comment: Yes the 8-digit precision includes the leading 3 and seven decimals. But still I don't get why $3\sigma_{M} < 0.5 \cdot 10^-7$ and in the last equation I wrote I have $\pi$ in there, what am I missing? how to compute $\sigma_{M} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi(4-\pi)}}{\sqrt{N}}$ if I don't know the value of pi nor the value of $\sigma_{M}$ which, btw, I believe the value of $\sigma_{M}$ has something to do with the precision and the confidence.

Comment: Ahh! That is where I used a crude estimate (compare a circle with a hexagon) $3<\pi<4$. This gives you an upperbound $\sqrt{\pi(4-\pi)}<\sqrt{3(4-3)}=\sqrt3$. The expected value of $M$ gives you the estimate of $\pi\approx 4M/N$. The deviation $\sigma_M$ is just about the accuracy. The function $p(1-p)$ reaches its maximum, when $p=1/2$, so you can use that as well. I used $p>3/4$ to get a little bit better result.

Answer (score 4):

The statistical analysis given in the other answer seems fine.

But the discussion of integrals is unnecessary, I think. The standard Monte-Carlo technique for estimating $\pi$ is to generate $N$ random points in a square centered at the origin -- say the square $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$. After generating each point $(x,y)$, you can check to see if $x^2 + y^2 < 1$, which tells you whether that point lies in the unit circle. You keep track of the fraction $k$ of random points that lie within the unit circle. As $N$ gets larger, this fraction $k$ gives increasingly accurate estimates of the ratio $\text{(area of circle)} / \text{(area of square)}$. In other words $k \approx \pi/4$, when $N$ is large, so $\pi \approx 4k$.

The statistical analysis given in the other answer tells you how large $N$ must be in order to achieve the desired accuracy with a desired probability.

There is a fairly good explanation on [this web page](https://web.archive.org/web/20171222045939/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51909.html).

And another one [on this page](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/329/lectures/node109.html).

Answer (score -1):

The usual trick is to use the approximation of 355/113, repeating multiples of 113, until the denominator is 355.  This version of $\pi=355/113$ is the usual implied value when eight digits is given.

Otherwise, the approach is roughly $\sqrt{n}$

Comment: But that's not a Monte-Carlo approach, which is what the OP requested.

Comment: There is in Martin Gardner, an experiment dropping pins onto parallel lines, which produces pi in its outcome.  The experiment is run for 355n, until the outcome is 113n.  i

Answer (score -1):

Basically, it is about the standard deviation of the Binomial distribution (a single independent experiment is called Bernoulli experiment, with a mean of p and the variance of p-p^2). For B(n,p), the variance is np(1-p), the standard deviation is  $$ \sqrt{p(1-p)/n} $$

In our case of Monte Carlo simulation, p = pi/4

Lastly, we need to time 4 to get pi. So $4*\sqrt{p*(1-p)/n}=1.642*\sqrt{1/n}<10^{-8}$, get n> 2.7e16

Comment: -1. This is a very sloppy answer. You are using $\pi$ to compute $n$ needed to compute $\pi$. It is circular reasoning. Look at Jyrki Lahtonen's answer posted a long time ago.

Comment: I only need a rough Pi to calculate n so it is no problem.  To get high accuracy, it will be better to have an initial value.  The basic point of my answer is to use variance.  It is a relatively simple and short answer.

Comment: I suppose I was a bit severe. You did get the gist of the problem. It is better to use a bound though. If you edit your answer to make the point clear, I will put back the point taken.